# Tensorflow placeholder shape with the two first shapes as None

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm just started to learn Tensorflow (v. 2.1.0) and Python (v. 3.7.7).

I have found this lines of codes:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

support_set = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, img_height, img_width, channels])
query_set = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, img_height, img_width, channels])

y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, None])
```

When I convert to version 2, with this code:

```
support_set = np.zeros([None, None, img_height, img_width, channels], tf.float32)
query_set = np.zeros([None, None, img_height, img_width, channels], tf.float32)
y = np.zeros([None, None], tf.int64)
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

What mean those two None mean at the beginning of the placeholder shape?

You can find the original code, the one I want to migrate to with Tensorflow 2, [here](https://github.com/sudharsan13296/Hands-On-Meta-Learning-With-Python/blob/master/03.%20Prototypical%20Networks%20and%20its%20Variants/3.3%20Omniglot%20Character%20set%20classification%20using%20Prototypical%20Network.ipynb).

Answer (score -1):

You don't have corresponding code in v2, or tf.keras.layers.Input() might be the one. tf.placeholder is low leve API. This was used in "Define-and-Run" style. You define model with tf.placeholder. In v2, you are supposed to write in "Define-by-Run" style.

See snippet from [TensorFlow 2 quickstart for experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/advanced).

```py
class MyModel(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
    self.flatten = Flatten()
    self.d1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
    self.d2 = Dense(10)

  def call(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.d1(x)
    return self.d2(x)

# Create an instance of the model
model = MyModel()
```

Also, See snippet from [Effective TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2). Those classes inherits from tf.keras.Model.

```py
class DynamicRNN(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, rnn_cell):
    super(DynamicRNN, self).__init__(self)
    self.cell = rnn_cell

  def call(self, input_data):
    # [batch, time, features] -> [time, batch, features]
    input_data = tf.transpose(input_data, [1, 0, 2])
    outputs = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, input_data.shape[0])
    state = self.cell.zero_state(input_data.shape[1], dtype=tf.float32)
    for i in tf.range(input_data.shape[0]):
      output, state = self.cell(input_data[i], state)
      outputs = outputs.write(i, output)
    return tf.transpose(outputs.stack(), [1, 0, 2]), state
```

You can also write your model with keras api.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape)
h = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='SAME')(x)
h = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(h)
h = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='SAME')(h)
h = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(h)
h = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='SAME')(h)
h = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(h)
h = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(h)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(h)
model = tf.keras.Model(x, y)
```

==== EDITED ====

```
support_set = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, img_height, img_width, channels])
query_set = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, img_height, img_width, channels])
```

can be replaced with

```py
import tf
support_set = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[None, img_height, img_width, channels])
query_set = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[None, img_height, img_width, channels])
```

, where Input doesn't need explicit Batch size. You can find more information on
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't understood anything. You can find the original code here: https://github.com/sudharsan13296/Hands-On-Meta-Learning-With-Python/blob/master/03.%20Prototypical%20Networks%20and%20its%20Variants/3.3%20Omniglot%20Character%20set%20classification%20using%20Prototypical%20Network.ipynb